# Connect Rails/Unicorn/Nginx container to MySQL container

Tags: mysql, docker, containers

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735529/docker-image-from-existing-rails-unicorn-mysql-app) thread, I am trying to create 2 containers: 1 with a rails app, and the other with a MySQL database but I keep getting the `Mysql2::Error (Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'` in my apps production.log file after I hit the container's IP `http://192.168.59.103`

When I start the rails container, I am attempting to link them and do get an error if I specify an incorrect MySQL name.  What am I missing to successfully link the containers so the full app runs in containers?

**Rails container command**

```
docker run --name games-app --link test-mysql:mysql -p 8080 -d -e SECRET_KEY_BASE=test sample_rails_games_app
Here are my files:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Publish port 8080
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["bundle", "exec","unicorn", "-p", "8080"]
CMD ["bunde", "exec", "rake", "db:migrate"]
```

**Rails database.yml (dev and test are the same as production)**

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  host: localhost
  #socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
 <<: *default
  database: weblog_production
```

**7/31/15 Edit**

The docker log shows the unicorn server running:

```
docker logs a13bf7851c6d
I, [2015-07-31T18:10:59.860203 #1]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=9
I, [2015-07-31T18:10:59.860583 #1]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2015-07-31T18:10:59.864143 #1]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2015-07-31T18:10:59.864859 #7]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=7
I, [2015-07-31T18:10:59.865097 #7]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2015-07-31T18:11:01.796690 #7]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

**7/31/15 Solution Thanks to @Rico**

1. `db:migrate` was having problems running so I ultimately ran it by hand in a `docker run` command.  Make sure you do this after the container is already created, or during the creation process as it needs the linking to the DB container
2. This [linking article](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) helped me understand that my link was not being created so there was no way to communicate properly.
3. Once I understood how to accurately make the link, I did update my database.yml with the host and port values
4. Use this command to check the names of your env variables `docker run --rm --name <unique-value> --link <db-name> <non-db-image> env`.
5. Use this to see the value of the links in your app container `docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.Links }}" <app-name>`

Comment: I should give this question 10 ups... it saved my day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your `bundle exec unicorn -p 8080` `CMD` is superseding the `bundle exec rake db:migrate` as it doesn't return.

You should run your `db:migrate` first and you should run it with the `RUN` command as `CMD` is the primary command in docker.

But the other problem is with your `database.yml` file. You are pointing your db to a db server that runs on the same container as in the application.  You should populate the values of your `database.yml` from the env variables created after you link your source container (application) to destination container (db server container). The env variables are created in the source container.

More info here: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/

So for example:

```
$ docker run --rm --name web2 --link db:db training/webapp env
. . .
DB_NAME=/web2/db
DB_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.5:5432
DB_PORT_5432_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.5:5432
DB_PORT_5432_TCP_PROTO=tcp
DB_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=5432
DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.5
```

Your `database.yml` should look something like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  database: <%= ENV['DB_NAME'] %>
  username: root
  password: root
  host: <%= ENV['DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['DB_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT'] %>
```

Comment: you win the gold star for today!  This got me most of the way there and I was finally able to link to the DB container with a modified command, and validating that link.  I ultimately had to run the db:create command in another Docker run command so I should probably just package that up in the Dockerfile better.  Thank you so much for your help!  Updated commands coming to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have 2 CMD commands in your Dockerfile, in fact only the last one is kept. The CMD command executed is `

CMD ["bunde", "exec", "rake", "db:migrate"]`

the other, the

`CMD ["bundle", "exec","unicorn", "-p", "8080"]`

is superseded.

See Supervisor

https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

if you want to run more than one rocess in your container, or run 2 differnet containers

Comment: Thanks @user2915097.  I wasn't totally sure about that but the problem still persists if I only have the unicorn command, and the unicorn server is running either way.